# How to implement indexed [] default property

Tags: delphi, class

I have a class which holds multiple filenames inside a TStringList. I can access a particular filename by index using:

```
myclass.stringlistclass[index]
```

But how can I get an filename using the following syntax?

```
myclass[index]
```

Is there a property I can implement to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
private
  function GetColumnValue(const ColumnName: string): string; overload;
  function GetColumnValue(Index: Integer): string; overload;
  procedure SetColumnValue(Index: integer; const Value: string);
public
  property Values[const ColumnName: string]: string read GetColumnValue; default;
  property Values[ColumnIndex: integer]: string read GetColumnValue write SetColumnValue; default;
end;
```

This means:

- you can have multiple `default` indexor properties
- the multiple indexor properties can have the same name *e.g.*, `Values`
- the properties getters can be overloads (*i.e.* have the same name) *e.g.*, `GetColumnValue`
- Delphi will resolve the overloads by type signature

Comment: you also need `FilesCount` property with `getFilesCount` method

Comment: @teran depending on code logic it's acceptable to return empty value for non-existent index.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp Indeed, I have done exactly this, passing empty strings if index doesn't exist.

Comment: very beautiful and powerful usage

Answer (score 14):

Use "default" keyword on the indexed property. <del>There can be one default property per class.</del>

You can have multiple default properties per class, however these default properties must have the same name.

An example:

```
    property Item[const Coordinate: TPoint]: TSlice read GetSlice write SetSlice; default;
    property Item[x,y: integer]: TSlice read GetSlice write SetSlice; default;
```

You can even have the getters and setters share the same name, as long as they have the `overload` directive.

Comment: Actually, it's possible to have multiple `default` properties per class.  [Example Declaration](http://pastebin.com/tbXS6BXX)

Comment: @afrazier is it some recent addition to the language? Previously there seemed to be only one default property.

Comment: My personal Hg repo dates back to Apr 2008 w/ Delphi 2006 with working code in it.  The code itself is older -- I'm pretty sure that it worked with Delphi 2005.  I'm not sure how much farther back it goes, and I only have Delphi 2007 installed for my legacy projects.

Comment: Since I have access to Delphi 7 right now, I've discovered that you can't do multiple default properties in a class with it.